# Is there a way to zoom the Visual Studio text editor with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Yesterday I found myself needing to zoom my Visual Studio text editor and was without a mouse (don't ask). Typically I do this by holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and scrolling the mouse wheel. I also couldn't figure out how to tab into the area where you can specify your zoom level in the lower left hand corner of the text editor window.

[image: zoom in the lower left corner of the text editor window]

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there a menu setting somewhere that I could have navigated to via the keyboard to set my zoom level?
2. Even better is there a similar keyboard command to holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and scrolling the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I don't know if there is a menu option, but there are keyboard shortcuts to set the zoom level.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to Zoom In

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to Zoom Out

Comment: Perfect this was definitely my preferred option. I try to avoid the mouse when I can. :)

Comment: @michael, whoops. Sorry for overwriting your edit. Thanks for the proper formatting.

Comment: Thank you! The period/comma didn't seem to be very meaningful, until this `http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/09/10/zooming-in-and-out-of-text-in-the-editor.aspx` pointed out it's also </>, "greater than" and "less than", which makes sense.

Comment: These shourtcuts are not present by default in the most recent versions of Visual Studio (more precisely, for some reason they are restricted to Image Editor only). If you want to keep using them, you have to manually reassign them as global shortcuts in keyboard options.

Comment: @Pierre I tried the msdn blog shortcuts within Visual Studio 2017 RC but they don't work! The ones in this answer still work.

Comment: For anyone else who finds those keys impossible to read: they are comma and period (i.e. full stop) respectively. Note that shift-comma is < (less than) and shift-period is > (greater than).

Comment: This also works for Visual Studio 2022!

Comment: I think it is possible to **create** a menu item, or a tool bar button. You use _Customize_, then you create commands _Zoom In_ and _Zoom Out_ (found under category _View_).

Answer (score 16):

In my case, ReSharper reassigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> ) to ReSharper's Recent Edits command, and I wanted to reset it back to Visual Studio 2012's zoom out.

To do that, go to Tools -> Options. Under Environment -> Keyboard, remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> hotkey from the ReSharper.ReSharper_GoToRecentEdits command (or any other commands), and assign the View.ZoomOut command back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (use either Global or TextEditor mode).

Answer (score 10):

[Visual Studio Code Linux keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf) for zoom in/out:

- in: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>
- out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

[image: Visual Studio Code Linux keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: this question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.
in Visual Studio, `Ctrl` + `-` is by default used for [navigating backward in cursor position history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/navigating-code?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for an answer to the first question (as I was), you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key three times. This works in VS 2019, but doesn't appear to work in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for 2020-Sep. Ver 1.49. Win 10:

From keyboard shortcuts in-app ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> .. or .. File Menu, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts):

Zoom In: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> .. or .. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Add</kbd> .. or .. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shft</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Zoom Out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> .. or .. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_Subtract</kbd> .. or .. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shft</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Reset Zoom: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_0</kbd>

NB: for VS-Code (may/Not be same ViZStd)

Answer (score 0):

The default accessibility setting by Microsoft, if they havent been tampered or changed are:

Zoom In --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Zoom Out --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

[Here is the link to the official Microsoft's VS code accessibility page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_zoom)

Hope it helps someone else

Comment: this question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.
in Visual Studio, `Ctrl` + `-` is by default used for [navigating backward in cursor position history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/navigating-code?view=vs-2022).